# Pi powerd OBD-II Computer

Tags: hardware, linux

I recently built an [OBDuino32k](https://code.google.com/p/opengauge/wiki/OBDuino32K) with my Arduino Uno. Unfortunately, I built the wrong interface, so I can't use it with my car. I built an interface for [ISO](https://code.google.com/p/opengauge/wiki/OBDuinoInterface#Interface_with_ELM) instead of [ELM](http://elmelectronics.com/DSheets/ELM323DS.pdf).

I bought a Raspberry Pi the other day, and I'm thinking, since I have already constructed the OBD-II to DB9 cables, I'm wondering if there's a way I can use that to finish my project. Does anyone know of any Linux OBD software that will run on the Pi? I've started searching, but haven't come up with anything yet. Gonna keep any progress posted here. Any insight this community could lend is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm also planning to connect my Pi to the OBD-II interface in my car. For the hardware I'm using a dongle that connects via bluetooth as that seems the easiest way to do it (no soldering for a start).

Comment: @Tom77 - Seems interesting. Do you have a blog or website tracking your project? I'd like to see it.

Comment: I guess now we could mention the carberry?
http://www.carberry.it/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've looked for the same thing for quite a while. Here is probably the most useful link I've found:

[KW1281 Live Diagnosis with Raspberry Pi](http://kaikretzberg.de/?p=1250)

The author reverse engineers a piece of software written for Windows by looking at the byte streams going between his computer and his car's computer. While the technical details are interested, he also provides snippets of source code that can be used.

His final conclusion is that the Raspberry Pi is not able to read from the OBD-II interface of a car while the engine is running. His reasoning is buggy serial drivers resulting in bad timing.

Here's another one that may provide a solution eventually, but mostly covers the hardware side for now:

[Raspberry Pi Car PC Project](http://wolframpc.blogspot.com/p/raspberry-pi-car-pc-project.html)

The author requested a [free STN1110 chip](http://www.obdsol.com/stn1110/) and plans on making a custom board to communicate with his car. If you do a search on the Raspberry Pi boards you will find a couple other people working on the same thing. I was even able to find a person working on a marketable version of such a board:

[OBD-II STN1110](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=8854)

The creator did not provide a website for ordering such a board that I'm aware of, but seems to offer them if you send a private message on the form.

There is also an android app called Torque that is available. I haven't managed to find source for it however.

**Some more potentially useful links:**

[pyOBD](http://www.obdtester.com/pyobd) - Open source (GPL) program written in python that interfaces with OBD-II. If that's not a perfect match for the Raspberry Pi, I don't know what is.

[openOBD: OBD-II Scan Tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openobd/) - An abandoned C++ based OBD-II program for both Windows and Linux based systems.

**Edit 7/28/2013**

There was a blog post on [RaspberryPi.org](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) today with some more good information:

Here's a link to the blog: [Carputers – some ideas to get you started](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/4462)

A link to a forum post of a guy who put a PI in his F150: [My Pi Carputer in my truck](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3//viewtopic.php?f=41&t=50495).

[A link to his github source](https://github.com/martinohanlon/pyobd).

Another project with OBD and GPS: [OBD GPS Logger](http://icculus.org/obdgpslogger/)

Software written for the above that simulates OBD: [OBDSim](http://icculus.org/obdgpslogger/obdsim.html)

I have a feeling that if I don't start working on this soon there wont be anything left to develop.

Comment: Please only use links as an *additional resource*, not your main one. We need you to describe what those links say.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I'm gonna check these out! Looks like promising info to build upon.

Comment: @xxmbabanexx Added a description of link content and a bit more info.

Comment: *Much* better. This is an *awesome* answer.

Answer (score 4):

You might find this project interesting: [My Raspberry Pi Project - OBD2 Data Recorder](http://www.pistonheads.com/gassing/topic.asp?t=1216528). A guy has created a ODB2 data logger for his motorbike using a Raspberry Pi.

He includes links to github where you can find the source code as well as detail about the USB -> OBD2 interface he used.

There is also a pair of guys in the process of creating an OBD2 logging app using a Raspberry Pi, check out their blog: [Pimyride with David and Alan](https://ca326project.wordpress.com/).